# Facebook JS Authentication on my whitelabeled domains

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm redesigning a social auth component in our app. Our app requires user to login via Facebook before any content can be downloaded.

Currently we do server side oauth to download what they need.

Our goal is to have the JS auth, sexy popup without redirections.

Our content can live on 2 different URLS:

- **subdomain**.app.com, where **subdomain** can be an alphanumeric string
- anydomain.tld which is an alias to **subdomain**.app.com. No redirections required, content rendered as if you were on **subdomain**.app.com

Now I know that JS auth requires "App domains" defined in Facebook app settings. The first type of URL goes through our admin, so they could just add the subdomain to Facebook app settings. However whitelabelled subdomains are 100% in hands on end users and they don't have access to our app.

So my question is, what are my options? Is it even possible, to do what I want without involving humans?

Thanks, Michal

Comment: You can not add any arbitrary number of domains to an app. Normally your app works on _one_ domain (and any subdomains thereof), as a “hack” you can supposedly get a couple more to work by using different domains for platforms website, canvas, page tab and mobile site, but that would be it. Apart from that, you need to use either individual apps per domain, or redirect to your app’s “main” domain and handle login from there.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I though there may be some clever cookie/token exchange whatever that could work...but I doubt that :)

Comment: One addition. Let's assume that I create a special subdomain **oauth.app.com** which would also be specified in FB app settings, could I use the JS popup somehow?

Comment: As long as you are “on” `oauth.app.com` when you embed the JS SDK …

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll close the question

Answer (score 0):

After the comments and investigation, this is not possible. I'll have to revert to the regular 3 legged oauth.